# using setParameter with createNativeQuery very slow

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

we are trying to improve a performance with JPA with mysql, the code:

```java
    private String getProfileIdsSQL = "select up.user_profile_fk, up.Profile_id from account_config.user_profile as up " +
            " where up.user_profile_fk IN (%s)";
.
.
.
            String sql = String.format(getProfileIdsSQL, preparePlaceHolders(foreignKeys.length));
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
            for (int i = 0; i < foreignKeys.length; i++) {
                query.setParameter("p" + i, foreignKeys[i]);
            }
.
.
.
    protected static String preparePlaceHolders(int length) {
        if (length == 0)
            return "";
        int capacity = length * 4;
        StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder(capacity);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            ans.append(":p").append(i).append(",");
        }
        ans.setLength(ans.length() - 1);
        return ans.toString();
    }
```

Run Very slowly but if i skip the parameter binding and write the values in the query string without `setParameter` the result is very fast but we can't do it in production, how can we make `setParameter` work faster ?

Thanks.